# How to use variables in a systemd service file?

Tags: service, systemd, environment-variables

I'm creating a service file for a daemon, and I would like to use variables (in init scripts I used environment variables) to define some parameters for the executed scripts. For example, I would like to use 2 parameters $PARAM1 $PARAM2:

```
[Unit]
Description=my daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/daemon1
PIDFile=/var/run/daemon1.pid
EnvironmentVariable=PARAM1=123
EnvironmentVariable=PARAM2=444
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/wget -O - --post-data=key1=$PARAM1&key2=$PARAM2 http://192.168.1.2/log.php
ExecStopPost=-/usr/bin/wget -O - --post-data=key1=$PARAM1 http://192.168.1.2/log.php
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Needless to say, this example doesn't work. Is there something like this achievable with systemd? What kind of parametrization of exec commands is possible?

Comment: The ExecStartPre line uses $PARAM1 and $PARAM2. I'd also dearly like to know if these can be used and where they can be set, which isn't addressed in the current answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The directive is [`Environment`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=), not `EnvironmentVariable`.

> ```
> Environment=
> ```
>
> Sets environment variables for executed processes. Takes a
>   space-separated list of variable assignments. This option may be
>   specified more than once, in which case all listed variables will be
>   set. If the same variable is set twice, the later setting will
>   override the earlier setting.

```
Environment=PARAM1=123
Environment=PARAM2=444
```

OR

```
Environment=PARAM1=123 PARAM2=444
```

Not sure, but you may need to use them inside braces `{}`:

```
--post-data=key1=${PARAM1}&key2=${PARAM2}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a variable that can be used in both [Unit] and [Service] sections?

Comment: These are *environment variables*. They are not used in sections, but passed to the processes. In this particular case they are referenced in the command line of `ExecStart(Pre|Post)?`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific, include an example? It does not work for me. I tried to reference the variables set but it looks like it does not resolve them. I tried with and without braces.

Comment: The `Environment` directive is only for creating variables in the environment of the called process, not variables in the service file itself? could you please include this info in your answer?

Comment: How does "_Sets environment variables for executed processes._" not already cover this?